# Tomcat 6 crashes under CentOS 5

Tags: centos, tomcat, java

We have CentOS 5, OpenJDK 1.6 and Tomcat 6.

Every week or two our server fatally crashes with the following output in catalina.out:

```
Exception while removing reference: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.disposeNativeScaler(Native Method)
        at sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.dispose(FreetypeFontScaler.java:167)
        at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:146)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Exception while removing reference: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.disposeNativeScaler(Native Method)
        at sun.font.FreetypeFontScaler.dispose(FreetypeFontScaler.java:167)
        at sun.java2d.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:146)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002aaaab621c28, pid=12911, tid=1158957376
#
# JRE version: 6.0_17-b17
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (14.0-b16 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.7.5
# Distribution: Custom build (Wed Oct 13 13:04:40 EDT 2010)
# Problematic frame:
# J  java.lang.String.getBytes(Ljava/lang/String;)[B
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid12911.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
#
```

Could someone tell us how should we solve such a problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's in /tmp/hs_err_pid12911.log?

Comment: Threads, processes, system dump.

Comment: the hs_err should point to a "Library" and a "Current Java thread:" which caused the crash. Can you post those?

Comment: Current thread (0x000000001084a000):  JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=14517, stack(0x0000000045044000,0x0000000045145000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x000001000000001c

Comment: The full log can be viewed there:
http://var.imagebook.ru/tmp/hs_err_pid12911.log

Answer (score 3):

Usually OpenJDK gives lots of problems. I recommend you to install Sun JDK instead.

- Download JDK from Oracle/Sun http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
- Install it. Note: The installation will be placed wherever you run it. So if you run it form your Desktop, it will be installed there.
- If you like to use alternatives to add Oracle JDK as default Java program:

  alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk1.6.0_25/bin/java 2

  alternatives --config java

  Select Oracle/SUN JDK
- Set JAVA_HOME in your tomcat, edit catalina.sh and add:

  export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.6.0_25

Answer (score 0):

There is some recent activity in bug tracker of OpenJDK related to this crash:
http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1326
http://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=2160

Target fix version is icedtea-2.5.4 which should map to a OpenJDK7 version following u71b14 (since [u71b14 corresponds to icedtea-2.5.3](http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page)).